# How do I show that the ideal $(2)$ of $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$ is not flat?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, exact-sequence

> Let $R=\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$ and let me take the ideal $(2)\subset R$. I want to show that $(2)$ is not flat in $R$.

We only had the following definition:

> A module $M\subset R$ is flat if $M\otimes_R-$ is left exact.

Using this definition I want to show it.

My idea was the following. Since we know that tensoring is already right exact we only need to worry about left exactness. The problem is that I don't see what left exact sequence I need to consider such that after tensoring it isn't left exact anymore. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Isn't $(2)=(0)$?

Comment: @azif00 sorry I made a typo in the question, I edited it, so I don't think $(2)=(0)$ anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you intend to look at modules over the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, consider the short exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} 
\to \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} 
\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} 
\to 0, 
$$
where the left map is multiplication by $2$, embedding $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ into the regular module $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ as the submodule, i.e. ideal, $(2)$. Can you see how tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ destroys injectivity?

After tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, the map
\begin{align}
\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} &\otimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} 
&&\;\longrightarrow\; 
&\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} &\otimes \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \\
x &\otimes y &&\;\longmapsto\; &x &\otimes 2y
\end{align}
sends
$$
1 \otimes 1 \;\longmapsto\; 1 \otimes 2 
= 2 \otimes 1 = 0 \otimes 1 = 0 \otimes 0, 
$$
i.e., it's the $0$ map, which is clearly not injective.

Here it is all summarized in a commutative diagram of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$-modules, where the vertical maps are all isomorphisms and the numbers labeling the other arrows are where the class of $1$ or $1 \otimes 1$ is sent (which determines maps since they're cyclic modules):
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> 
\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} 
@>{1 \otimes 2}>> 
\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} 
@>{1 \otimes 1}>> 
\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}
@>>> 0 \\
@. @V{\sim\,}VV @V{\sim\,}VV @V{\sim\,}VV @. \\
0 @>>> 
\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} @>{\smash[t]{0}}>> 
\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} @>{\smash[t]{1}}>>
\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} @>>> 0
\end{CD}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I first have a quick understanding question. Is it true that $(2)=\{\bar 0,\bar 2\}$ in $R$ since $\bar 2\cdot 2=\bar 4=\bar 0$ and $\bar 3\cdot 2=\bar 6=\bar 2$?

So tensoring with $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ gives me $$0\rightarrow \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\otimes\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\rightarrow \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\otimes \Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}\rightarrow ...$$
Now what I don't see is what $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\otimes\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ gives me. Or isn't this necessary to solve the exercise?

Comment: I would say that all the elements which maps to $0\otimes 0$ are $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\otimes \bar 0$?

Comment: Yes, but note that it's best to think of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ as a module in the middle of the sequence. It's a tautology that a submodule of the regular module is the same set and underlying additive abelian group as an ideal of the ring (but you no longer consider multiplying elements together within the submodule).

Comment: Sorry is your yes with respect to my claim that $(2)=\{\bar 0, \bar 2\}$ or is it with respect to my claim that I would say that the kernel of the embedding is $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\otimes \bar 0$ or for both?

Comment: I was responding to your first comment. I will edit my answer to address your further question.

Comment: okey perfect thanks!

Comment: Have a look now. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer. There is something I do not see. Why is $0\otimes 1=0\otimes 0$? I mean $1\neq 0$ in $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$

Comment: And sorry ca you see your diagram because I can‘t see it on the phone but maybe I need to go on the laptop tomorrow

Comment: You can pass any scalar (element of the ground ring $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$) across the tensor product, which is what I'm doing back and forth in those equations: 
$$
0 \otimes 1 = (0 \cdot 0) \otimes 1 = 0 \otimes (0 \cdot 1) = 0 \otimes 0
$$

Comment: Ah okey makes sense but $2\otimes 1=1\otiems 2$ could also be explained by the symmetrie instead of moving $2$ right?

Comment: No. Although there exists an isomorphism $M \otimes N \to N \otimes M$ (when the ring is commutative), that's not what's happening here. We are not *mapping* $m \otimes n \mapsto n \otimes m$. Instead, that equality takes place in $M \otimes N$. Those two expressions **are the same element** in this module!

Comment: We are passing scalars across $(mr \otimes n = m \otimes rn$ for any $m \in M$, $\,n \in N$, and $r \in R$:
$$
1 \otimes 2 = 1 \otimes (2 \cdot 1) = (1 \cdot 2) \otimes 1 = 2 \otimes 1, 
$$
but in the left factor $2 = 0$ (even though it didn't in the right factor).

Comment: By the way, I took [a screenshot of the commutative diagram](https://imgur.com/a/8sJdega). Perhaps you can see this on a mobile device.

Comment: Perfect thanks. Yes now it is clear thanks a lot!